# How to display a record that has no relation to a table

Tags: php, laravel

What I need is to count the number of vehicles created by each user, but the problem is that when I make the query for the relationship, it only brings up the users who have vehicles created, but I also need to show the users who do not have vehicles created.

```
public function clients()
{
    $user_id = \Auth::user()->id;

    $users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('mechanic_client', 'users.id', '=', 'mechanic_client.user_id')
        ->where('mechanic_client.mechanic_id', '=', $user_id)
        ->select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.email', 'users.password', 'users.url', 'users.cant_vehicle');
        

    $vehicles = DB::table('vehicles')
             ->joinSub($users, 'users', function ($join) {
                 $join->on('vehicles.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
             })->select('users.id', 
                        'users.name', 
                        'users.email', 
                        'users.password', 
                        'users.url', 
                        DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
             ->groupBy('user_id')->get();

   return $vehicles
}
```

**what i get**

| id | name | email | vehicles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65 | name1 | name1@name1 | 5 |
| 66 | name2 | name2@name2 | 1 |
| 67 | name3 | name3@name3 | 6 |

These are the users who have vehicles created, but what I need is to show all the independent users who have or do not have vehicles and also count the vehicles of each user.

Comment: You need `LEFT JOIN` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#left-join-right-join-clause

Comment: Start from `users` and use `LEFT JOIN` on `vehicles`.

Comment: the answer is already been given. I just want to point out another aspect. why you are retrieving the password from the users table? I can't see why it will be needed.

Comment: $vehicles = DB::table('users')
                ->leftJoinSub($users, 'vehicles', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('users.id', '=', 'vehicles.user_id');
                })->select('users.id',
                           'users.name', 
                           'users.email', 
                           'users.password', 
                           'users.url',
                           'users.cant_vehicle', 
                           DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                ->orderBy('users.id')->groupBy('user_id')->get();  @Samir

Comment: it doesn't work throw me that SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vehicles.user_id' in 'field list' @Samir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never the best option to use the raw `DB::` query builder in `Laravel`. This could be very easily achieved with `Eloquent` approaches. `Laravel` has `withCount()` for counting relationships, described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships). For check if mechanicClint exists, you can use has() method, that check if the relationship exists.

```
User::has('mechanicClients')
    ->withCount('vehicles');
```

This requires you to define the class and relationship. In `Users.php`.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Models\Vehicle;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public function vehicles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Vehicle::class);
    }

    public function mechanicClients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MechanicClient::class);
    }
}
```

And define the `Vehicle.php` and `MechanicClient.php` models.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vehicle extends Model
{

}

class MechanicClient extends Model
{

}
```

Comment: $users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('mechanic_client', 'users.id', '=', 'mechanic_client.user_id')
        ->where('mechanic_client.mechanic_id', '=', $user_id)
        ->select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.email', 'users.password', 'users.url', 'users.cant_vehicle');                                                                                                                   I understand, but how do I bring specific users? @mrhn

Comment: $vehicles = User::withCount('vehicles')->where('id', '=', $users)->get(); @mrhn

Comment: What do you mean by "but how do I bring specific users"?

Comment: How do I send multiple users to this User :: withCount ('vehicles'); @mrhn

Comment: You dont send users User::withCount(); will take all users

Comment: $ users = DB :: table ('users') -> join ('mechanic_client', 'users.id', '=', 'mechanic_client.user_id') -> where ('mechanic_client.mechanic_id', '=', $ user_id) -> select ('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.email', 'users.password', 'users.url', 'users.cant_vehicle');

is that I don't need all the users, I need the users that I create a user, like this in the above query